# Is it possible to write an equation for which any point on the coordinate plane could be a solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I realize this may not make sense at first, so I'll explain. I'd like to know if it is possible to write an equation for which you could insert any x value, and at the same time any y value, and the equation still work, giving you infinite simultaneous x and y values as solutions rather than a line. It wouldn't be a function and it would have a domain of {-∞,∞} and range of {-∞,∞} where there was no relation between the x and y values. Is this even possible, and if so what would that equation be? I tried googling this but couldn't find a single link that even touched on the concept.

Comment: $ x+ y = x+y $.

Answer (score 1):

Any identity, as $x^2-y^2=(x+y)(x-y)$, can work.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it would be something simple that I wasn't thinking of!